# When to Define "unit" in the TypeSpecifierList for Erlang Bins

Tags: erlang

I've started learning Erlang and recently wrapped up the section on bit syntax. I feel I have a firm understanding of how they can be constructed and matched but failed to come up with an example of when I would want to change the default values of "unit" inside the TypeSpecifierList.

**Can anyone share a situation when this would prove useful?**

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes, just for convenience: you've got a parameter from somewhere (e.g., from a file header) specifying a count of units of a given size, such as N words of 24-bit audio data, and instead of doing some multiplication, you just say:

```
  <<Audio:N/binary-unit:24, Rest/binary>> = Data
```

to extract that data (as a chunk) from the rest of the file contents. After parsing the rest of the file, you could pass that chunk to some other function that splits it up into samples.